# Which of the conditions are necessary to determine the reason for the area?

Tags: geometry

I have this statement:

[image]

My development was:

The $\triangle{BPC}$ have an area of $\frac{ah}{2}$, where $h =$ Height

The $\triangle{DPA}$ have an area of $\frac{at}{2}$, where $t = $ Height

The quadrilateral $ABCD$ have an area of $ak$, where $k =$ Height

So, area of $\triangle{BPC} + \triangle{DPA} = \frac{a}{2}(h+t)$

And the reason is $\frac{\frac{a(h+t)}{2}}{ak}$

This is only taking into account condition 1, but I could not achieve more.

The correct answer must be $D)$, but i cant understand how is it possible.

Then, ¿How can I get to the correct answer, and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The quadrilateral $ABCD$ have an area of $ak$, where $k =$ Height

In the case of a parallelogram, the height is the distance between $\,BC\,$ and $\,DA\,$ so $\,k=h+t\,$.

> And the reason is $\;\displaystyle\frac{\;\;\frac{a(h+t)}{2}\;\;}{ak}$

You must mean the ratio (not reason). Yes, which (again, for a parallelogram) simplifies to $\,\dfrac{1}{2}\,$.

Comment: But $AC$ isn't diagonal

Comment: @Mattiu You are right, and the drawing is misleading. Answer corrected.

Comment: why is h + t = k

Comment: @Mattiu Because $h$ and $t$ are altitudes which are drawn perpendicular to $BC$ and $DA$ respectively. Since $BC || DA$ in a parallelogram, it follows that the altitudes are also parallel and, given that they have the common point $P$, they both lie on the same line. That line is perpendicular to $BC$ and $DA$ so the segment between the intercepts on $BC$ and $DA$ is precisely the height of the parallelogram i.e. $k$.

Comment: Well, and with the information of i) can be solved, so ii) implies the i) , so each one by itself. Thanks!

Comment: @Mattiu That's correct, the answer is **D**.

Comment: An another answer can be:  If you draw a parallel line that contains the point $P$, now you have two parallelogram with area $\alpha + \beta$, so the triangles, $\triangle{APD}, \triangle{BPC}$ have a $(\alpha)/2$ and $(\beta)/2$ area, respectively, so the total area of triangles is $(\alpha + \beta)/2$

Comment: @Mattiu Right, that's a good argument as well.

Answer (score 1):

You found this expression:
$$\frac{\left(\frac{a(h+t)}{2}\right)}{ak}.$$

You can convert this into a simpler expression that has just one horizontal bar
(a single fraction with a numerator and a denominator).
You should be able to simplify it further by cancellation.

To get a definite fraction of the area, you must also relate
$h + t$ to $k.$
Think about how the height of a triangle or parallelogram
(relative to a base $AD$ or $BC$) is measured,
and what that says about the relationship among $h,$ $t,$ and $k.$

To see this better, you may (for sake of argument)
assume either of the statements i) or ii);
then try  drawing 
the height of triangle $\triangle ADP$ on the base $AD,$
the height of triangle $\triangle BCP$ on the base $BC,$
and the height of parallelogram $ABCD$ between the bases $AD$ and $BC.$

Comment: Edited, the correct answer must be D